# Sending newsletter to all emails from db

Tags: php, email

I am trying to implode a variable, am I doing it right?  The objective is to get all the emails from a table and then go through them one by one.

The page just displays white.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once '../includes/conn.php';

if(!$user->is_loggedin()){
    $user->redirect('../users/login.php');
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM newsletter");
$stmt->execute();


while ($userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $addresses[] = $userRow['email'];
}   
$to = implode(",", $addresses);
$subject = "";
$from = "newsletter@epicowl.uk";
$headers "From Epic Owl's Newsletter" . $from;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: `$headers "From Epic Owl's Newsletter" . $from;`. Missing the `=`, don't know why error reporting failed there. Also the from header I believe is `From: name <email>`.

Comment: While you can assemble multiple email addresses into `To:`, it depends on your MTA if they're all sent. There's usually a limit. Moreover you don't want all recipients to see the whole list there.

Comment: the title of your question can be interpreted as if a modest suicide bomber is seeking advice ... ;-)

Comment: Use an echo statement to see what the $to variable contains - echo $to;

Comment: Thanks guys, guessing a for each is the way to go to not show all email addresses to everyone then?  And to the long userblahblah, can't get the echo result as is white page no error showing to fix.

Comment: Did you see my comment about error? You could `bcc` all addresses, not sure hwo spam filters would like that though.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't fix the white page issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send each message uniquely, if you're sending to an entire list:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once '../includes/conn.php';

if(!$user->is_loggedin()){
    $user->redirect('../users/login.php');
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM newsletter");
$stmt->execute();

while ($userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $to = $userRow['email'];
    $subject = "";
    $from = "newsletter@epicowl.uk";
    $headers = "From Epic Owl's Newsletter" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Also if your MTA has limits, you can stagger the sending. For example, if the limit is 500/hour, send 100/15min. This will ensure you do not exceed the limit. I do hope you have an opt-out on there too and your list is Double Opt-In verified. Welcome to becoming a potential Spammer.

Comment: This is just for me to learn PHP, so the MTA limit is not an issue, there is also an opt out :)  I will fully test shortly, thanks!

Comment: Works a treat, just have to setup an if statement for the submit button now, top job!